# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)

Tags: mysql

I tried to deploy web application on my server and I am getting this mysql database exception

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)`

I tried to access the database from the command prompt using `mysql -u root -p` I am able to do all the database operations.

what is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3649)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at com.mpigeon.DbConnection.DbConn(DbConnection.java:26)
    at com.mpigeon.CheckLoginHome.doGet(CheckLoginHome.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Assuming you're using JDBC, can you provide the full error message (SQLException.getMessage()) and stack trace?

Comment: password of connection string is wrong 
try mysql -u root -h localhost -p

Comment: @Daniel : i have posted the error message kindly have a look and kindly help me out

Comment: A quick solution can be found here in the answer of [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/46908573#46908573)

Comment: Please check, if there are no spaces in the password provided.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to grant access to root from localhost. Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) ubuntu help

Comment: I have the same problem that this question. But I have grant access to my user and I continue with the same problem :(

Comment: Yakshemash ! How do I do this if it happen in a windows 7, 64 bits ?

Comment: Please post the answer itself, not links (which may disappear).

Answer (score 9):

try using `root` like..

```
mysql -uroot
```

then you can check different user and host after you logged in by using

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user;
```

Answer (score 6):

check you are putting blank space in password.

Answer (score 6):

**From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49080720/1224827), thought this might be useful:**

I tried many steps to get this issue corrected. There are so many sources for possible solutions to this issue that is is hard to filter out the sense from the nonsense. I finally found a good solution [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password):

**Step 1: Identify the Database Version**

```
$ mysql --version
```

**You'll see some output like this with MySQL:**

```
$ mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**Or output like this for MariaDB:**

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Make note of which database and which version you're running, as you'll use them later. Next, you need to stop the database so you can access it manually.

**Step 2: Stopping the Database Server**

To change the root password, you have to shut down the database server beforehand.

**You can do that for MySQL with:**

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

**And for MariaDB with:**

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mariadb
```

**Step 3: Restarting the Database Server Without Permission Checking**

If you run MySQL and MariaDB without loading information about user privileges, it will allow you to access the database command line with root privileges without providing a password. This will allow you to gain access to the database without knowing it.

To do this, you need to stop the database from loading the grant tables, which store user privilege information. Because this is a bit of a security risk, you should also skip networking as well to prevent other clients from connecting.

**Start the database without loading the grant tables or enabling networking:**

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

The ampersand at the end of this command will make this process run in the background so you can continue to use your terminal.

**Now you can connect to the database as the root user, which should not ask for a password.**

```
$ mysql -u root
```

You'll immediately see a database shell prompt instead.

**MySQL Prompt**

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**MariaDB Prompt**

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Now that you have root access, you can change the root password.

**Step 4: Changing the Root Password**

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now we can actually change the root password.

For **MySQL 5.7.6 and newer** as well as **MariaDB 10.1.20 and newer**, use the following command:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

For **MySQL 5.7.5 and older** as well as **MariaDB 10.1.20 and older**, use:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Make sure to replace `new_password` with your new password of choice.

**Note:** If the `ALTER USER` command doesn't work, it's usually indicative of a bigger problem. However, you can try `UPDATE ... SET` to reset the root password instead.

***[IMPORTANT] This is the specific line that fixed my particular issue:***

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

Remember to reload the grant tables after this.

In either case, you should see confirmation that the command has been successfully executed.

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The password has been changed, so you can now stop the manual instance of the database server and restart it as it was before.

**Step 5: Restart the Database Server Normally**

The tutorial goes into some further steps to restart the database, but the only piece I used was this:

**For MySQL, use:**
    $ sudo systemctl start mysql

**For MariaDB, use:**

```
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Now you can confirm that the new password has been applied correctly by running:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

The command should now prompt for the newly assigned password. Enter it, and you should gain access to the database prompt as expected.

**Conclusion**

You now have administrative access to the MySQL or MariaDB server restored. Make sure the new root password you choose is strong and secure and keep it in safe place.

Comment: step5 failed for me due to some log file, need to rename /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control to another name

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error after upgrading MySQL server from 5.1.73 to 5.5.45
There is another way to fix that error.

In my case I was able to connect to MySQL using root password but MySQL actively refused to GRANT PRIVILEGES to any user;

1. Connect to MySQL as root

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

   then enter your MySQL root password;
2. Select database;

   ```
   use mysql;
   ```
3. Most probably there is only one record for root in `mysql.user` table allowing to connect only from `localhost` (that was in my case) but by the default there should be two records for root, one for `localhost` and another one for `127.0.0.1`;
4. Create additional record for root user with `Host='127.0.0.1'` if it's not there;

   ```
       SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO mysql.user SELECT ',
               REPLACE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'user' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql')
               ,"Host","'127.0.0.1'"),
               ' FROM mysql.user WHERE User="root"'); 

        PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
        EXECUTE stmt;
   ```
5. Additionally to that you can execute `mysql_upgrade -u -p`
   to see if everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens if you did not set the password on install, in this case the mysql using unix-socket plugin.

But if delete the plugin link from settings (table mysql.user) will other problem. This does not fix the problem and creates another problem. To fix the deleted link and set password ("PWD") do:

1) Run with --skip-grant-tables as said above.

If it doesnt works then add the string skip-grant-tables in section [mysqld] of /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. Then do  sudo service mysql restart.

2) Run mysql -u root -p, then (change "PWD"):

```
update mysql.user 
    set authentication_string=PASSWORD("PWD"), plugin="mysql_native_password" 
    where User='root' and Host='localhost';    
flush privileges;

quit
then sudo service mysql restart. Check: mysql -u root -p.
```

Before restart remove that string from file mysqld.cnf, if you set it there.

@bl79 is the author of this answer, i've just reposted it, because it does help!

Comment: thankyou, thankyou, thankyou!  this is the only solution that worked after hours of research

Comment: @user3217883 if it really worked for you, you may vote this answer :)

Comment: This is not my post.  I just found your answer during research of the same problem.

Comment: upvoted for referencing unix-socket. It appears 99% of the posts talk about how resetting the password and making no reference to the socket which, if in place, rendered the password not working. Poor documentation.

Comment: it's the "mysql_native_password" bit that did it for me that helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

My application is using Mura CMS and I faced this issue. However the solution was the password mismatch between my mysql local server and the password in the config files. As soon as I synched them it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the empty users creating by MySQL. I only have root user and my own user. I deleted the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Update the empty password in the table mysql.user of mysql

```
use mysql;
select host,user,password from mysql.user;
update mysql.user set password = PASSWORD('123456') where password = '';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Note that the `WHERE` clause you're showing here will reset the password of ALL the users who don't have one. Not just the root user (i.e. `WHERE User = 'root'` maybe?)

Comment: Logged in just to say this is the only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Update **user** table in **mysql** DB. And set some password where it is blank, i was using root user so i set password for root user.

```
update mysql.user set password = PASSWORD('123456') where password = '';
flush privileges;
```

And then again tried from ATG CIM by providing password and it worked fine.

[image: After update]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lchp.png

Comment: Note that the `WHERE` clause you're showing here will reset the password of ALL the users who don't have one. Not just the root user (i.e. `WHERE User = 'root'` maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today while installing SugarCRM (a free CRM).

The system was not able to connect to the database using the root user. I could definitively log in as root from the console... so what was the problem?

I found out that in my situation, I was getting exactly the same error, but that was because the password was sent to mysql directly from the `$_POST` data, in other words, the `<` character from my password was sent to mysql as `&lt;` which means the password was wrong.

Everything else did not help a bit. The list of users in mysql were correct, including the anonymous user (which appears after the root entries.)

Answer (score 0):

I googled a lot but did not find a definite answer to my problem. I used KeyPass to generate a strong password and could use it successfully on mysql workbench to connect but not from the command line. So I changed the psw to an easy one and it worked on the command line.  I have managed to create a strong password that was able to connect from the terminal. So my advise is, try with an easy password first before trying all kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I was running UTs and I started receiving error messages. I am not sure what was the problem. But when I changed my encoding style in INTELLIJ to UTF8 it started working again.

> access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)
>   hibernate

this is my URL
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf8

Answer (score 0):

Add a user option in msyql.

```
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209996/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) will be useful.