# As a root user Access is denied ROOT@LOCALHOST using password yes

Tags: mysql

I am a Linux user and I have updated my root password in mysql as :

```
update user set password=PASSWORD('xxxx') where user='root' and host='localhost';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

When I tried to login as :

`mysql -u root -p
xxxx`

`An Error occurred :- Access denied for 'ROOT'@'LOCALHOST' using password yes`

What could be the problem? I know how to reset the mysql root password through terminal using root user. I just wanted to know why didn't this work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror

Comment: r u restart mysql server?

Comment: Did you check if your password was changed? Maybe the where clause did not match. Do a `select user, password, password('xxxx') from user` and see if the passwords match

Comment: sorry i didn't get you..,

Comment: yes i even checked it, everything is fine.., but i don't know why it saying access denied ..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enter the password with the command line call, append it directly to the `-p` flag:

```
mysql -u root -pxxxx
```

or just leave it blank, then mysql will ask about it:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Entering it directly to the command is not desireable, as it might show up in the process list and the shell history, so if you want it for personal use and not in a script, use the `-p` without a password

Comment: How does this address OP problem? This should be a comment, not an answer IMHO...

Comment: Hm, i thought maybe the password was entered in a wrong way

Comment: If the password is wrong, it is both on console that in a script.. agree?

Comment: sorry i entered it as the same way shown above it didn't work.