# Error:java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, xampp

I am USING mysql (XAMPP) on my netbeans.

I am trying the query

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but cant't connect:

```
  ERROR: java.sql.SQLException:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Here the whole code:

```
    public class NextHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    try{

        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database2";
        String username= "root";
        String password= " ";
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        Statement stat=con.createStatement();
        String Query=
        "INSERT INTO donor_info(donor_id,donor_lastname,donor_firstname,donor_middlename,donor_age,donor_weight,donor_height,donor_gender,donor_contact_number,"
                + "medical_condition)VALUES ('"+txtdonorid.getText()+"','"+txtlname.getText()+"','"+txtfname.getText()+"','"+txtmname.getText()+"',"
                + "'"+txtage.getText()+"','"+txtweight.getText()+"','"+txtheight.getText()+"')";

        stat.execute(Query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Donor Added to Database");
    txtdonorid.setText(null);
    txtlname.setText(null);
    txtfname.setText(null);
    txtmname.setText(null);
    txtage.setText(null);
    txtweight.setText(null);
    txtheight.setText(null);

    }
    catch (SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.toString());
    }
    bloodtype f=new bloodtype();
    f.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
    f.run();
    }
        }


     public void run(){

    //setUndecorated(true);

     setSize(1920, 1200);
     setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     setVisible(true);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      donorinfo f = new donorinfo();
      f.run();
      }
      }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror)

Comment: I tried it but there is still an error, it.. Are my codes correct(GUI) . ? What should i do..

Comment: When i run this code, the frame appear, then when i click the nexthandler button to save it on my database, this error appears ..

Comment: is your password really a whitespace? String password= " ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you run your query you have to run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Your code is taking a space as password. Please change `password =" "` to `password=""`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your connection string.
String password = " ";

Change it to String password = "root";
(If still there is error please try this in command prompt and see what happens.
mysql -u root -p (press enter)
password : root