# Access denied connecting from java to mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying connect to database from java and get the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'gda'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

but using same credentials from command line I'm connect

```
server$ mysql -ugda -pgda
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2666453
Server version: 5.5.39-36.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 36.0, Revision 697

Copyright (c) 2009-2014 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

on another database my java work fine and able connect. seems to be an issue at database level ?! what I need to fix at database level ?

adding the code of the connection:

```
public Connection getConnection() {     
    try {
        Class.forName(jdbcDriver);

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception:" + ex.getMessage());
        errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

where:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db?user=gda&password=gda
```

Comment: can you show the code of the connection?

Comment: i don't know i get this credentials from our dba, i guess he changed the root password

Comment: Maybe it can help (Similar Question) Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954740/errorjava-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhostlocalhost

Comment: I had that error, I was using an incorrect password

Comment: I had a similar issue but with php. Instead of using `localhost`, try using `127.0.0.1`, that worked for me.

Comment: from command line work with that password, same i use in the java code

Comment: for 127.0.0.1 i get com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant Java code?

Comment: added the java code ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the username and password in this manner:

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/xyz";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password";

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: I doubt that this will fix the problem, perhaps it should be posted as a comment?

Comment: if not address the issue, I think its worth a try.

Comment: tried but does not work, i created a new user and was able to connect using old java code. so it's something wrong with user at database level. I addressed this to our dba