# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Rails 2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I create a database in mysql
i'm using mysql2 gem and Rails 2
i've already saw some question here about this, but non of them works for me.

I have my database.yml file like so:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db
  username: root
  password: 'root'
  host: localhost
```

i can login into mysql in the command line like this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and enter the same password: root and i have no error, but when i try to see a page after running scrpit/server the application always show the error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Any idea what could be happening here please?
Thanks

Comment: can you remove single quotes from root like 'root' to root

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081358/155826

Comment: Haver you tried connecting via the socket method? `socket:` is also a valid parameter and should be the path to where your MySQL socket is.

Comment: @Thorin yes i try that, doesn't work.
@mysmallidea in my case i says `using password: NO` but when i enter a incorrect password i yes `using password: YES` i try folling the guied but i face a error in one of the commands
@tadman yes i try that, i says the same

Answer (score 0):

replace for this:

```
  development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: gradesfirst
    username: root
    password: ''
    host: localhost
```

or assign a password for the root user on mysql.

Comment: thanks for the reply 
I already tried that, it doesn't work, also as i mention in the question the password is there which is root, i can login to mysql via terminal using the password root, but in rails i still have the same error: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: try to create a new user for mysql, grant permissions and set a password, then use that user to log in rails.