# MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-connection

Consider:

```
./mysqladmin -u root -p** '_redacted_'
```

Output (including typing the password):

> Enter password:
>
> mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error:
> **'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror)

Comment: @clearlight Is not same question, this post is a problem with mysqladmin win super privilegies into mysql, the other post is a problem with a simple connection from socket.

Comment: Try remove if exists `~/.my.cnf` file.

Comment: I know this is old, but want to say this for future visitors. Don't enter your mysql password, especially for root, in the command itself, or it will be stored in your shell history. Just leave the `-p` option by itself and mysql will prompt for a password.

Comment: For MySQL 8 use 
sudo mysql_secure_installation
and set an strong password.

Ref. Check step 5 of this tutorial https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 662, accepted):

1. Open and edit `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, depending on your distribution.
2. Add `skip-grant-tables` under `[mysqld]`
3. Restart MySQL
4. You should be able to log in to MySQL now using the below command `mysql -u root -p`
5. Run `mysql> flush privileges;`
6. Set new password by *`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';`*
7. Go back to /etc/my.cnf and **remove/comment** skip-grant-tables
8. Restart MySQL
9. Now you will be able to login with the new password `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Hello,
I had the same problem.
I did the above, and it solve the problem, but everytime I reboot CentOS, I need to do all of the steps again (I got the message:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
- when run the command mysql (or any sql command) and I do again and again all over as above at each reboot.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as Eitan does.

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me.  All other of trying to skip grant tables running mysql --skip.., etc. failed

Comment: More details about this solution here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Too bad that this does not work with MariaDB: ``You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword'' at line 1``

Comment: In my case I've added `skip_grant_tables` (mysql5.7)

Comment: it works. @PhilippLudwig you might need to use different way. In my case will be use mysql; then  UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASS') where USER='root';

Comment: I found this to work @PhilippLudwig `set PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');` I did this after step 5. Here is how my command prompt output looked: `MariaDB [(none)]> 
MariaDB [(none)]> set PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Comment: For step 3 restart MariaDB: I found the following works: `sudo systemctl restart mariadb`

Comment: Some may find the file in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded

Comment: As an alternative, you can execute `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` and open a second terminal to enter `mysql -u root -p` without the need to modify and configuration files.

Comment: @Eitan permissions matter, chances are you have installed mysql when logged as root user. try `sudo su` and `mysql -u root -p` and you'll logged in without issue, but with big security concerns..

Comment: I use mac and I run this command "$ sudo find / -name my.cnf" to find location of my.cnf  , and it worked after follow above steps.

Comment: If you get: "You are using MariaDB as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to modify user settings" you can find solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926467/you-are-using-mariadb-as-an-anonymous-user

Comment: Found my file in this directory -> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d

Comment: this trick appears to no longer be valid.  Server version 5.7.27 forbids altering the root password while --skip-grant-tables is in effect

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 and MySQL 5.7.28, the config file is placed at /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: When I want to alter the password I get the following error (MySQL8) `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

I've followed this suggestions to fix it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: that solved it in fedora30, the config file was under /etc/my.cnf.d/community-mysql-server.cnf Many thanks @Kishore Venkataramanan

Comment: best solution. i am using ubuntu 20.04 configuration file path is
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, I just add that I had to add 'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';' at point 6 (it was auth_socket by default)

Comment: I was able to run `mysqladmin --user=root password "password"` after the second step

Comment: The top answers are ALL BAD. To save hours of time use this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155034/4759176

This answer in particular costed me an hour. DON'T USE THIS ANSWER. EDITING THE CONFIG FILE results in `Couldn't connect` error which leads you down a new rabbithole. For your sake use the answer I linked above ^

Comment: Is it really so complicated and why. I had to do the steps from this answer, and the steps from two other answers just to have the localhost user working.

Comment: I changed it with `sudo vim /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` on a raspian install of mariadb. Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be also good to temporarily turn off remote port or add firewall rule so no one could connect from the network in the meantime.

Comment: after given command running `sudo mysql` it throws error ``ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Whoever reads this - I discovered that for mysql running from docker container my password was too long for client to be able to successfully authenticate with it. I shrank the password to 79 characters and this solved my problem. This problem seems to be linked with mysql client itself, because joomla app which was using another user with long password was happily authenticating to that very same server.

Comment: Worked for RedHat 7

Answer (score 1071):

All solutions I found were much more complex than necessary and none worked for me. Here is the solution that solved my problem. There isn't any need to restart *mysqld* or start it with special privileges.

```
sudo mysql

-- for MySQL
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';

-- for MariaDB
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('root');
```

With a single query we are changing the **auth_plugin** to **mysql_native_password** and setting the root password to **root** *(feel free to change it in the query)*.

Now you should be able to log in with root. More information can be found in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html#alter-user-password-management) or [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/#authentication-options).

*(Exit the MySQL console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or by typing **exit**.)*

Comment: I'm unable to do this... "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...".

Comment: This answer worked, I accidentally added is not useful answer vote, excuse me!

Comment: Single line version: **sudo mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'"**

Comment: Worked very well on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @TCB13 and anyone else facing this issue.  "I 'm unable to do this... "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near... ".  
Use FLUSH PRIVILEGES before executing the alter command

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: This worked a treat for me as well, thank you!  I was able to log in fine from the command line but not over TOAD using an SSH tunnel using the same credentials.  It was driving me nuts so I'm rapt that it's working now.

Comment: This locked me out, even sudo mysql no longer works. Had to completely remove mysql and reinstall.

Comment: ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements seems you have to set a very secure password with version 5.7.27

Comment: @Josh You need to change your mysql policy. `sudo mysql` and then `SET GLOBAL validate_password_length = 4;`

Comment: Those guys who have problems  with ERROR in SQL syntax, check your `mysql --version`. If you have 8+, the `INDENTIFIED BY` keyword has changed. Therefore this fix is for mysql5.7.

Comment: Finally, an answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: even if it says 0 rows affected it will update the password to be 'root'

Comment: Still works in `MySQL 5.7.31`, 2020. I changed the password to empty and my configurations are correct, but I couldn't login with root, this saves my time. Thank you.

Comment: This worked! Wanted to note something a bit misleading that happened to me. When I entered it, it returned `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`. As if it didn't do anything, but it still worked. Because when I try to connect to it, now it works and I did nothing else between. Thanks again for this. Lifesaver.

Comment: Yay! Ubuntu 20.04 solution. (I'm getting real tired of MySQL screwing with things like this). @harsh-trivedi this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: For those getting an MariaDB error listed on the top comment, please scroll down to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57311757/1463744 which worked for me!

Comment: `sudo mysql` gives `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` (both with and without the password)

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 21.04. Thanks!

Comment: Worked, but I wish I knew why my MySQL root password keeps getting reset. I know I'll have to deal with this problem again and again.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I spent 2 hours looking for an answer to this problem. You saved my day. Worked on Ubuntu 21.10. Thanks!

Comment: I am on mysql 8.0.28, ubuntu 20.04.3. This solution worked. I can now do "mysql -u root -p" and get in. HOWEVER, sudo mysql does not work anymore. I get an error - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.

Comment: The USING clause at the end of the Mariadb command is only valid in Mariadb v10.4 onwards: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/#authentication-options

Comment: Worked very well on Ubuntu 22.04 , Thank you sir!

Comment: @jjxtra I thought I was locked out too, but it turns out the default password is just "root"

Answer (score 138):

None of the previous answers helped me with this problem, so [here's the solution I found](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04).

The relevant part:

> In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), the root MySQL user is set to authenticate using the auth_socket plugin by default rather than with a password. This allows for some greater security and usability in many cases, but it can also complicate things when you need to allow an external program (e.g., phpMyAdmin) to access the user.
>
> In order to use a password to connect to MySQL as root, you will need to switch its authentication method from auth_socket to mysql_native_password. To do this, open up the MySQL prompt from your terminal:
>
> > `sudo mysql`
>
> Next, check which authentication method each of your MySQL user accounts use with the following command:
>
> > `SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`
>
> Output
>
> > ```
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > | user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > | root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
> > | mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > | mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > | debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> > ```
>
> In this example, you can see that the root user does in fact authenticate using the auth_socket plugin. To configure the root account to authenticate with a password, run the following ALTER USER command. Be sure to change password to a strong password of your choosing, and note that this command will change the root password you set in Step 2:
>
> > `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`
>
> Then, run FLUSH PRIVILEGES which tells the server to reload the grant tables and put your new changes into effect:
>
> > `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
>
> Check the authentication methods employed by each of your users again to confirm that root no longer authenticates using the auth_socket plugin:
>
> > `SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`
>
> Output
>
> > ```
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > | user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > | root             | *3636DACC8616D997782ADD0839F92C1571D6D78F | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > | mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > | mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > | debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
> > +------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
> > 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> > ```
>
> You can see in this example output that the root MySQL user now authenticates using a password. Once you confirm this on your own server, you can exit the MySQL shell:
>
> > `exit`

Comment: Worx also for `mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))` on `ubuntu 20.04`. Cheers

Comment: Anybody facing the issue for MySQL inside Docker.. this is the solution for you guys.
Thanks!

Comment: In Debian 10, the plugin  is not auth_socket but  `unix_socket`.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting problems (also in the first revision)?

Comment: I'm recieving this error, why? `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'MYPERSONALPASSWORD'' at line 1` I've just pasted this line: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MYPERSONALPASSWORD';`

Comment: @FernandoTorres I've just tested that line and it worked as expected. You could try cop/pasting the line again, manually typing it out, and/or switching to a new terminal instance

Comment: by far the most simple and best answer here!!!

Answer (score 90):

I tried many steps to get this issue corrected. There are so many sources for possible solutions to this issue that is is hard to filter out the sense from the nonsense. I finally found a good solution [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password):

**Step 1: Identify the database version**

```
mysql --version
```

**You'll see some output like this with MySQL:**

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**Or output like this for MariaDB:**

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Make note of which database and which version you're running, as you'll use them later. Next, you need to stop the database so you can access it manually.

**Step 2: Stopping the database server**

To change the root password, you have to shut down the database server beforehand.

**You can do that for MySQL with:**

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

**And for MariaDB with:**

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
```

**Step 3: Restarting the database server without permission checking**

If you run MySQL and MariaDB without loading information about user privileges, it will allow you to access the database command line with root privileges without providing a password. This will allow you to gain access to the database without knowing it.

To do this, you need to stop the database from loading the grant tables, which store user privilege information. Because this is a bit of a security risk, you should also skip networking as well to prevent other clients from connecting.

**Start the database without loading the grant tables or enabling networking:**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

The ampersand at the end of this command will make this process run in the background so you can continue to use your terminal.

**Now you can connect to the database as the root user, which should not ask for a password.**

```
mysql -u root
```

You'll immediately see a database shell prompt instead.

**MySQL Prompt**

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**MariaDB Prompt**

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Now that you have root access, you can change the root password.

**Step 4: Changing the root password**

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now we can actually change the root password.

For **MySQL 5.7.6 and newer** as well as **MariaDB 10.1.20 and newer**, use the following command:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

For **MySQL 5.7.5 and older** as well as **MariaDB 10.1.20 and older**, use:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Make sure to replace `new_password` with your new password of choice.

**Note:** If the `ALTER USER` command doesn't work, it's usually indicative of a bigger problem. However, you can try `UPDATE ... SET` to reset the root password instead.

***[IMPORTANT] This is the specific line that fixed my particular issue:***

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

Remember to reload the grant tables after this.

In either case, you should see confirmation that the command has been successfully executed.

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The password has been changed, so you can now stop the manual instance of the database server and restart it as it was before.

**Step 5: Restart the Database Server Normally**

The tutorial goes into some further steps to restart the database, but the only piece I used was this:

**For MySQL, use:**

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

**For MariaDB, use:**

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Now you can confirm that the new password has been applied correctly by running:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

The command should now prompt for the newly assigned password. Enter it, and you should gain access to the database prompt as expected.

**Conclusion**

You now have administrative access to the MySQL or MariaDB server restored. Make sure the new root password you choose is strong and secure and keep it in safe place.

Comment: The ALTER USER statement was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: Wow ! this very line `mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';` has been such a life saver for me !

Comment: I use MariaDB 10.3.25 and this worked: `mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');`

Comment: I like this method, as it allowed me to temporarily create a database backup without permanently amending permissions, although it may have been better to not run `mysqld_safe` in the background as I seemed to get issues afterwards trying to kill it and then get the mysql service running normally again (although a full Linux restart seemed to do the trick).

Comment: `-bash: mysqld_safe: command not found`   `AlmaLinux release 8.5 `

Answer (score 63):

After trying all others answers, this it what finally worked for me:

```
sudo mysql -- It does not ask me for any password

-- Then in MariaDB/MySQL console:
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

I found the answer in the blog post *[Solved: Error “Access denied for user ‘root’@’localhost’” of MySQL — codementor.tech](https://medium.com/@chiragpatel_52497/solved-error-access-denied-for-user-root-localhost-of-mysql-programming-school-6e3611838d06)* (Medium).

Comment: THIS PLUGIN LINE IS REALLY HELPFUL. I tried a lot of compinations but this is the only worked for Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: This helped me with mysql 5.7 as well. So applicable not only for mariadb

Comment: I just used this on MySQL 8 Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked.  Other answers using `skip-grant-table` (my.conf or in `mysql` command) didn't work.  I could get in using a service account (https://askubuntu.com/a/120769/169836) but `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root';` didn't work.  Only when when using the plugin part did things work.  Thanks~

Comment: This helped me with my sql 8 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What is that plugin supposed to do? Can you link to official documentation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57311757/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This locked me out and I am no longer able to login with root. It just keeps throwing ```Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)```. As I am able to login with other users, I ran ```SELECT user,password_last_changed FROM mysql.user;``` and it shows that the password is not updated. Then why the hell I am not able to login? This is weird.

Answer (score 40):

## For Ubuntu/Debian users

*(It may work on other distributions, especially Debian-based ones.)*

Run the following to connect as `root` (without any password)

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

If you don't want to add `--defaults-file` each time you want to connect as `root`, you can copy `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` into your home directory:

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/debian.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

And then:

```
sudo mysql
```

Comment: This was all it took. 'root' is not 'root' on Ubuntu by default, apparently.

Answer (score 37):

In my experience, if you run without sudo it will not work. So make sure your command is;

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: This should be the acepted answer. The question is not about a forgotten password, but about the error message, because you cannot login as root without running with sudo privileges.

Comment: The top answers are ALL BAD. To save hours of time use this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155034/4759176

Comment: This should be the top answer. Take my upvote. Thank you

Comment: Extended in [Waterreedshimmer Dracchingan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/68874182#68874182).

Answer (score 20):

For new Linux users this could be a daunting task. Let me update this with MySQL 8 (the latest version available right now is 8.0.12 as on 2018-09-12)

1. Open "mysqld.cnf" configuration file at "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/".
2. Add **skip-grant-tables** to the next line of [mysql] text and save.
3. Restart the MySQL service as "sudo service mysql restart". Now your MySQL is free of any authentication.
4. Connect to the MySQL client (also known as mysql-shell) as **mysql -u root -p**. There is no password to be keyed in as of now.
5. Run SQL command **flush privileges;**
6. Reset the password now as **ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';**
7. Now let's get back to the normal state; remove that line "skip-grant-tables" from "mysqld.cnf" and restart the service.

That's it.

Comment: `mysql -u root -p`  still ask for password `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: @Salem try with sudo, that should work

Comment: when I ran these steps I get this error at step #6 : "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement"

Answer (score 14):

In my case under Debian 10, the error

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

was solved by (*good way*)

```
sudo mysql -u root -p mysql
```

*Bad way*:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Just giving the permission with sudo (without password) so executed like:
sudo mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 12):

My Station here:

- UBUNTU **21.04**
- PHP **5.6.40-57**
- MYSQL **5.7.37**

let's config it

```
nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

at the bottom, write this

```
skip-grant-tables
```

reload it

```
service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 8):

I did this to set my root password in the initial set up of MySQL in OS X. Open a terminal.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

Close the terminal and open a new terminal.

And the following worked in Linux, to set the root password.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

(`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`: This did not work for me the first time. But on the second try, it was a success.)

Then log into MySQL:

```
mysql -u root

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now change the password:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Restart MySQL:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 5):

In your [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench), you can go to the left sidebar, under Management select "Users and Privileges", click root under User Accounts, in the right section click tab "Account Limits" to increase the maximum queries, updates, etc., and then click tab "Administrative Roles" and check the boxes to give the account access.

Answer (score 5):

Use [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to alter your password:

```
sudo mysql

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'insert_password';
```

Source: *[Phoenixnap - Access denied for user root localhost](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/access-denied-for-user-root-localhost)*

Answer (score 4):

Ugh - nothing worked for me! I have a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7.4 machine running MariaDB 5.5.64.

I had to do this, right after installation of MariaDB from [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software));

```
systemctl restart mariadb
mysql_secure_installation
```

The `mysql_secure_installation` will take you through a number of steps, including "Set root password? [Y/n]". Just say "y" and give it a password. Answer the other questions as you wish.

Then you can get in with your password, using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It will survive

```
systemctl restart mariadb
```

**The Key**

Then, I checked the `/bin/mysql_secure_installation` source code to find out how it was magically able to change the root password and none of the other answers here could. The import bit is:

```
do_query "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('$esc_pass') WHERE User='root';"
```

...It says `SET Password=...` and not `SET authentication_string = PASSWORD...`. So, the proper procedure for this version (5.5.64) is:

Log in using `mysql -u root -p`, using the password you already set.

Or, stop the database and start it with:

```
mysql_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

From the *mysql>* prompt:

```
use mysql;
select host,user,password from user where user = 'root';
(observe your existing passwords for root).
UPDATE mysql.user set Password = PASSWORD('your_new_cleartext_password') where user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
select host,user,password from user where user = 'root';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Kill the running mysqld_safe. Restart MariaDB. Log in as root: `mysql -u -p`. Use your new password.

If you want, you can set all the root passwords at once. I think this is wise:

```
mysql -u root -p

(login)
use mysql;
select host,user,password from user where user = 'root';
UPDATE mysql.user set Password = PASSWORD('your_new_cleartext_password') where user = 'root';
select host,user,password from user where user = 'root';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

This will perform updates on all the root passwords: i.e., for "localhost", "127.0.0.1", and "::1"

In the future, when I go to [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 8 or what have you, I will try to remember to check the */bin/mysql_secure_installation* and see how the guys did it, who were the ones that configured MariaDB for this OS.

Answer (score 3):

## Fix for macOS

1. Install MySQL from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/ (8.x is the latest as on date, but ensure that the version is compatible with the macOS version)
2. Give password for `root` (let `<root-password>` be the password) during installation (don't forget to remember the password!)
3. Select **Use Legacy Password Encryption** option (that is what I had used and did not try for **Use Strong Password Encryption** option)
4. Search and open **MySQL.prefPane** (use search tool)

   1. Select **Configuration** tab
   2. Click **Select** option of **Configuration File**

      1. Select `/private/etc/my.cnf`
5. From terminal open a new or existing file with name `/etc/my.cnf` (`vi /etc/my.cnf`) add the following content:

   ```
    [mysqld]
    skip-grant-tables
   ```
6. Restart mysqld as follows:

   1. `ps aux | grep mysql`
   2. `kill -9 <pid1> <pid2> ...` (grab pids of all MySQL related processes)
7. `mysqld` gets restarted automatically
8. Verify that the option is set by running the following from terminal:

   ```
    ps aux | grep mysql

    > mysql/bin/mysqld ... --defaults-file=/private/etc/my.cnf ... (output)
   ```
9. Run the following command to connect (let `mysql-<version>-macos<version>-x86_64` be the folder where MySQL is installed. To grab the actual folder, run `ls /usr/local/` and copy the folder name):

   ```
    /usr/local/mysql-<version>-macos<version>-x86_64/bin/mysql -uroot -p<root-password>
   ```

Comment: The top answers are ALL BAD. To save hours of time use this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58155034/4759176

Comment: I just copy pasted the solution that worked for me on Mac OS. I hope it is useful. I did not try this fix on Windows or Linux, other solutions I think should work for other OSs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me and all the information in previous answers failed, proceed to *uninstall* all versions of MySQL on your machine, search for all remaining MySQL files using the command `sudo find / -name "mysql"` and `rm -rf` every file or directory with the "mysql" name attached to it (you should skip files related to programming language libraries).

Now install a fresh version of MySQL and enjoy. NB: You will lose all your data so weigh your options first.

Answer (score 2):

windows :

cd \Ampps\mysql\bin :

```
mysql.exe -u root -pmysql
```

after mysql start (you can see shell like this mysql> )
use this query :

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

try again access with root root

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you don't have enough privileges.

Type `su`, enter the root password and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a default password is set when you install it - as  [mentioned in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-rpm.html). This can be confirmed by the following command.

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot with the following answer:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('root');
```

And similar answers, my terminal was still throwing me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...

So after researching on the web, this line solved my problem and let me change the root user password:

```
sudo mysqladmin --user=root password "[your password]"
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is the from-host filter. It may be "localhost" by default. Are you trying to connect from a remote client? Change this to "%".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Arch Linux

Package: [mysql 8.0.29-1](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mysql)

What worked for me:

1. Edit my.cnf file, normally can be found at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and append this `skip-grant-tables` at the bottom/end of the file.
2. Restart mysql service by invoking `sudo systemctl restart mysqld`
3. Ensuring mysql service has started properly by invoking `sudo systemctl status mysqld`
4. Login to mysql using 'root' by invoking `mysql -u root -p`
5. Flush privileges by invoking `flush privileges;`
6. Create new user by `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'rootpassword';`
7. (If you plan to use this db with PHP), you should instead use this `CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'rootpassword';`
8. Check whether your changes have reflected in db by invoking the following in sequence:

   - `use mysql;`
   - `SELECT User, password_last_changed FROM user;`
9. Exit mysql console and comment/remove `skip-grant-tables` by editing my.cnf file (Refer to step 1 for the location)
10. Restart the mysql service (Refer to step 2 and step 3)

And that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you reached this page via Google like I did and none of the previous solutions worked, what turned out to be the error was 100% foolishness on my end. **I didn't connect to the server.** Once connected everything was smooth sailing.

In case it helps to know my setup, I'm using Sequel Pro and am trying to connect to it with Node using the NPM package, *mysql*. I didn't think I needed to actually connect (other than run Sequel Pro), because I was doing that from my application already.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while setting up the `mysql-8 zip` version. Finally, switched to `installer` version which worked seamlessly. During installation, there is a prompt to set up the `root` password. Once set, it works for sure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [MariaDB official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket), in MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the `unix_socket` authentication plugin is installed by default.

In order to disable it, and revert to the previous `mysql_native_password` authentication method, add line below in `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
unix_socket=OFF
```

And then run:

```sh
mysql_install_db --auth-root-authentication-method=normal
```

And then start `mysqld`

This command will then work fine:

```
mysqladmin -u root password CHANGEME
```

For additional information, see *[Configuring mysql_install_db to Revert to the Previous Authentication Method](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/#configuring-mysql_install_db-to-revert-to-the-previous-authentication-method)*.

Comment: What is the unix_socket thingy supposed to do and why is this change necessary? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66985012/edit) a little bit to your answer? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66985012/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to leverage [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) desktop on Mac to get 5.7.35 running and this **docker-compose.yml** configuration allowed it to work:

In particular it was the addition of the line...

> command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

...that did the trick

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'your_password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - ~/your/volume/path:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: ***Why*** does that work? What is the explanation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68623547/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue while integrating with Spring Boot and the issue for my case was quite direct.

I was trying to access root user but providing a wrong password under my application.properties

Solution is

- Either change the user from root to the actual user you want to access with the password provided

Example for my case I had provided a root instead of budget as username.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/budgetdb
spring.datasource.username=budget
spring.datasource.password=@@@password1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

- Or provide the right password for root user, which is essentially a potential reason for the issue.

  ```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/budgetdb
  spring.datasource.username=root
  spring.datasource.password=@@@Budget9650
  spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  ```

Answer (score -1):

The '-p' argument doesn't expect a space between the argument name and value.

Instead of

```
./mysqladmin -u root -p 'redacted'
```

Use

```
./mysqladmin -u root -p'redacted'
```

Or just

```
./mysqladmin -u root -p
```

which will prompt you for a password.

Answer (score -3):

Solution: **Give up!**

Hear me out. I spent about two whole days trying to make MySQL work to no avail, always stuck with permission errors, none of which were fixed by the answers to this question. It got to the point that I thought if I continued I'd go insane.

Out of patience for making it work, I sent the command to install SQLite, only using 450 KB, and it worked perfectly right from the word go.

If you don't have the patience of a saint, go with SQLite and save yourself a lot of time, effort, pain, and storage space..!

Comment: This is the first PEBKAC solution I've ever read on SO.

Comment: If software doesn't work without manually fixing or replacing it, on multiple occasions, the problem is NOT the user.