# Install mysql on centOS always return wrong root credentials

Tags: mysql, linux, root

I have installed mysql on CentOS, as described on https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7

Always on first installation I got a messagae after the command:

sudo mysql_secure_installation

> Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Here are some informations:
commands + results

cat /etc/*-release

> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) NAME="CentOS Linux" VERSION="7
>   (Core)" ID="centos" ID_LIKE="rhel fedora" VERSION_ID="7"
>   PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
>   CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7" HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
>   BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
>
> CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7" CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
>   REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
>
> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611
>   (Core)

cat /etc/redhat-release

> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

cat /proc/version

> Linux version 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64
>   (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org)  (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red
>   Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Aug 3 11:11:39 UTC 2016

My host name is not localhost, but root is always configured to 'localhost'.
Also, I have 'root' user for linux (same name for mysql) - I have tried both password of as linux root user and blank password, but still got the same error.

I have re-installed the mysql, but also got the same error.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

The steps:

```
1.Add skip-grant-tables under [mysqld] (nano etc/my.cnf) 
2.service restart.
3.flush privileges;
4.change root password (root) ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
5.Go back to /etc/my.cnf and remove/comment skip-grant-tables
6.Restart Mysql
```

After that, I have checked by command line:
telnet  3306, which seems to be correct.