# I can't access to my localhost/phpmyadmin (windows)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have all this error:

[image]

I go in `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin` and this is my `config.inc.php`:

```
     <?php
        /*
         * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
         * cookie
         */
        $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

        /*
         * Servers configuration
         */
        $i = 0;

        /*
         * First server
         */
        $i++;
        //I think there are something that I wrong
        // Other configuration
        // This is  a part of config.inc.php file
        /* Authentication type and info */
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
        $cfg['Lang'] = '';
        //other configuration
        /* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcpsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdfsdf */
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

        /* User for advanced features */
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

       ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Try this ->

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```