# You are using mariadb as an anonymous user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

All the privileges have been denied and all my databases seem to have been deleted. I get the error mentioned in the subject when I try to change the password.
Initially there was no password set and this behaviour started after executing the following command

```
update mysql.user set password=password('newpass') where user='root';
```

I enter mysql using:

```
mysql -u root
```

Every command I try to execute gives me access denied error. I tried surfing on google but did not get a solution to solve the issue.

Answer (score 21):

You must set the plugin of the user too, and flush privileges everytime

```
> update mysql.user set password=password('newpass') where user='root';
> flush privileges;
> update mysql.user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
> flush privileges;
```

Then check you are not using an anonymous user when the database instance starts: in your `/etc/my.cnf` remove/comment any line which looks like this

```
skip-grant-tables #comment with #
```

And restart the database

```
service <db> restart
```

Comment: Can't believe there is no mention of this in the MySQL docs. Or is this specific to MariaDB?

Comment: life-saving advice sir!!!   the "newpass" is your own password, but the plugin "mysql_native_password" is a hardcoded plugin which cannot be change.   most important you must highlight all these are executed as non-root user id, running the command "mysql -u root -p".

Comment: you saved my day with the command
   'update mysql.user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';'

Comment: Use [ALTER USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/) and [SET PASSWORD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/) rather than these underlying low level historical hacks especially as these [won't work in MariaDB-10.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540)

Answer (score -1):

```
> select version();
+----------------------------------+
| version()                        |
+----------------------------------+
| 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |
+----------------------------------+



# systemctl stop mariadb
# mysqld --skip-grant-tables  &
# mysql

>  flush privileges;
> update mysql.user  
       set authentication_string=password('789'),  
       plugin='mysql_native_password'  
       where user='root' and host='localhost';
>exit

# kill -15 $(ps aux | grep mysqld | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
# systemctl start mariadb
# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 789

MariaDB [(none)]> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

If mariadb >=10.2 then use ALTER USER (  [alter user announcement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-10-2/))