# Laravel shows error access denied for user

Tags: sql, laravel

I am new to laravel and trying to run the migration but it showing me following error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from informati   on_schema.tables
>   where table_schema = test1 and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

Comment: check .env file

Comment: The error means that you don't have valid connection to your database. Have you created a database for your project? In your `.env` file do you use the correct credentials to make the connection?

Comment: update .env files to vaild databse name and username and password

Comment: Check your database credentials properly in .env file.

Comment: Yes, @navkov I have created a database with name test1 in phpmyadmin and edited the .env file as follow, please check :

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: after configuring your .env file run "php artisan config:cache" command in te=he console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a database connection error.

**Solutions:**

If you are using a windows machine and XAMPP by default can use

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
 DB_HOST=localhost 
 DB_PORT=3306 
 DB_DATABASE=db_name
 DB_USERNAME=root 
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

If you are using a Linux machine and XAMPP by default can use also make sure the DB user has no password. Otherwise, you have to give DB password in `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Don't forget to clear the cache using `php artisan config:cache` artisan command.(if you made any changes in env you have clear config cache)

Answer (score 1):

Check in your .env environment file. Set DB_Username to root and leave blank in DB_Password

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

If, you have same as above.
Please clear cache with command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

or, simply, go to app projectName>bootstrap>cache and delete all files inside it.

Sometime, this is seen because of the cache files. or incorrect DB username and passowrd.

Comment: Instead of using two commands, we can achieve the same result with just "php artisan config:cache". Tx

Answer (score 1):

In the `.env` file Just set up correct DB credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE= // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME= // Your Database Username
DB_PASSWORD= // Your Database Password
```

`DB_USERNAME` should be set to **root** if you don't have a default username in the during installation of MySQL in XAMPP. If no password is set on the database, clear it `DB_PASSWORD`,

If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to restart your server after changing your `.env` file values.

Also, After completion of `.env` edit, enter this command in your terminal for clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

After you can be used run all of your outstanding migrations, execute the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`