# Laravel 7 access denied for user root password root

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the username: root and password: root. I cannot connect to my db whenever I type root in my password. It keeps saying `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` However, when I press enter leaving the password empty, I can go in.

In my .env file I have:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=fin_book_09
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I also changed my config/database to:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel shows error access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824248/laravel-shows-error-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: Clear your config and try again `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I tried that too and still not working, I don't understand

Comment: Can you confirm that you can connect to the database with those credentials i.e. does running `mysql -uroot -proot` allow you access or return an error?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Database connection in PHPMyAdmin. 
PHPMyAdmin Default 
user name: 'root'
Password : ''

for password set,
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('your_root_password');

Comment: is it not within the project files? Since I'm going to use `create database` right after?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving your application by laravel command `php artisan serve`. 
Then close that and serve again.

And if still not work try to regenerate your application key again.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Hope it helps :)