# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-8, ubuntu-18.04

I want to connect mysql db from my springboot project. My username and password is defined in "application.properties" file. I can use this username and password for connect mysql from terminal but the other side intellij cant connect with this informations. What should i do about this

I have changed the root password with a new password

This is my application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/(nameofdb)
spring.datasource.username=(root)
spring.datasource.password=(password)
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: have you followed exact steps like in this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is a reference for the wrong user or password in your database. It is not a problem from your Spring application.

I have checked on StackOverflow and check this link to help you with this problem. [MySQL Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to define the driver class : 
add this line and try

```java
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```