# Connect MYSQL DB on DigitalOcean MYSQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect MYSQL WorkBench to a db on digitalocean droplet.
I follow the link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-server-remotely-with-mysql-workbench

But still getting the following error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 through SSH tunnel at root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with user root
Cannot open SSH Tunnel: Connection refused
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upload your SSH key to gain access

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. It turned out somehow the password for the `root` MySQL user had changed from what I remembered setting it to. I was able to fix the issue by resetting the password by running the command specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908573/4115031).