# servlet.service error, classNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, vps

I am done building the java spring boot app and now I am trying to deploy it to VPS. Everything works except once I access part of web app that is connected to the database I get this error

> ERROR 7379 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

When I put connection url to database to be jdbc:mysql://"ip of server":3306/kuponi i get this error

and when I put connection url to database to be jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kuponi

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these dependencies to your **pom.xml** file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: didnt help much, now I get this error :   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:72) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]

Comment: yes, thanks, now i get diferent error, access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: yea, i made it work, now I am getting this error....  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: i made changes to my question

Comment: yes it is, I made mistake last time, check now ss

Comment: Just a tip, when uploading screenshots you should redact your server IP and username/password so that people with bad intentions can't see them.

Comment: ok, thanks for tips, I appreciate it

Comment: Can you connect to the database with a database client on your server?

Comment: yes, I can access database from terminal on my server, but my application cant

Comment: after typing this i get same error access denied , just it says '(using password:  YES)'

Comment: If you're absolutely sure credentials are correct you should try and check the database server logs.

Comment: If logs don't contain the reason then look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost