# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, hostname

I created my database offline using XAMPP. After uploading my site, I imported my database into server PHPmyadmin. Yet when if i load my website it will deny me access to the database displaying this error message:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user
> 'everjoe'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: The error message says `everjoe` not `root`.

Comment: Did you create the `everjoe` account? Did you grant it access to the database?

Comment: @Barmar I used everjoe as the user and i granted it access

Comment: @Barmar I used everjoe as the user and i granted it access

Comment: Are you having this problem in a PHP script or the PhpMyAdmin application?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

So could you check, if your Server of the Website is allowed in the SQL-Server, you can check that on the sql-console with the following command.

```
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
```

See here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#host-name-component for detailed information.

If there is still a Problem, maybe it is your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`-File
See here: [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is incorrect username and password, check your username and password details again

You could also go to `c:\xampp\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php`

Check for
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']`

You should see your phpmyadmin username and password.

Comment: i created those connections and it worked fine on my local host

Answer (score 0):

This means that the user has no access. This can be fixed in the following ways

```
insert into mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('setyourpasswordhere'));
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or if you are using SQL workbench, you can create an user under

```
Adminstration --> users and previlages --> click on Add account button and create a new user, with hosts as **%** and grant the previlages in Adminstrative roles, schema previalges tabs.
```

[image]