# How to grant root user in mysql database user table all privileges

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I accidentally removed all privileges for `root` user in `mysql` database `user` table.

By helping best at [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) I can now access database but I cannot grant all privileges to my `root` user at `localhost`.

Via PHPMyAdmin interface when I go and try to add, I get this error:

```
#1290 - The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

But I cannot access database and phpmyadmin without `skip-grant-tables` option.

This is the query runs but returns error:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 2147483647 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 2147483647 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 2147483647 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2147483647;
```

What should I do?

Comment: Any reason for withholding the exact error message you received?

Comment: Error message shows that you use MariaDB, not MySQL. This is another DBMS, similar, of course, but different nevertheless.

Comment: @Shadow this is the exact and the only error I got

Comment: @Akina yes that's mariadb. But not sure if they differ because syntax is the same as I know

Comment: Find another MariaDB of the same version. Execute`SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost;` on it. Copy the returned GRANT statements completely. Execute them on your server while `--skip-grant-tables`, then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and restart server without the option `--skip-grant-tables`.

Comment: @Akina `MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for root@localhost;` is the command, and 
`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` is the error in terminal

Comment: @Akina also `flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.025 sec)`

Comment: :facepalm: One more time: *Find **another** MariaDB of the same version.* Non-broken MariaDB server.

Comment: @Akina what do you mean?

Comment: Either find another server (of the same or maximally close but not below version) and look what privileges set must be assigned or install another MariaDB instance (in VM, for example) and copy needed privileges set.

Comment: @Akina the issue is I cannot grant privileges:(

Comment: When you start the server with `--skip-grant-tables` it disables account-management statements. You need to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` before account management statements will work. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic

Comment: @nnichols I cannot login to `mysql` without `--skip-grant-tables` options

Comment: I didn't say to start mysqld without `--skip-grant-tables`?

Comment: @nnichols sorry I did not understand your meaning. Should I start `mysql` without `--skip-grant-tables`?

Comment: Did you manage to run all the GRANTS for root@localhost?

Comment: @nnichols yes I did