# HikariPool- Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm creating a spring boot project. Then i try to connect mysql database to that project. I got the error called "HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization".

This is the whole stacktrace.

```
2022-01-15 11:09:29.374  INFO 2748 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2022-01-15 11:09:30.481 ERROR 2748 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]

2022-01-15 11:09:30.490 ERROR 2748 --- [nio-8888-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 

### Error querying database.  Cause:org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
### The error may exist in com/example/reservation/mapper/userMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.example.reservation.mapper.userMapper.findAll
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)] with root cause
My is as follows,application.yml

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
```

My is as follows,application.yml

```
server:
      port: 8888
spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/reservation?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC
        username: root
        password: "123456"
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

My dependancies are,pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>reservation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>reservation</name>
    <description>reservation project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

user.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class user {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

userMapper.java

```
public interface userMapper {
    @Select("select * from user")
    List<user> findAll();
}
```

userMapper.java

```
public class userController {

   @Resource
   userMapper usermapper;       
   @GetMapping()              
   public String hello(){
      return "hello";
   }
   @GetMapping("/user")          
   public List<user> getUser(){
        return usermapper.findAll();
   }

}
```

ReservationApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.example.reservation.mapper")
public class ReservationApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I access localhost:8888 it works successfully,

but when I access localhost:8888/user it gives an error

What happened?:(

> **reason**

I'm too stupid to have two MySQL services on my computer without noticing. 


    One of them is installed by myself(mysql57), the other exists in the PhpStudy integrated environment(mysqla).When I found out that there are two MySQL services in Windows services, I was stunned.Usually the service I use is mysql57, but my IDE accesses the service mysqla.

    When I first asked the question, the passwords for the root accounts of mysql57 and mysqla were 123456 and root respectively.When I tried many methods to no avail, I changed the password of the mysql57 root account and modified the configuration in the IDE at the same time.

    Then a magical scene happened, an error that should not have appeared in the IDE: database xxx does not exist.When I changed the database configuration in the IDE to the myql table that exists in every MySQL, visiting localhost:xx/user returned a set of Josn, then I realized that the problem was in my MySQL, okay Well, this is all caused by the usual habits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: This answer didn't solve my problem

Comment: why you have to add `/user` in `url(localhost:8888/user)`

Comment: I set an annotation   @GetMapping("/user")  ,Access it to get the data obtained by the database and return it in the form of json ,But don't know why it's not working .

Comment: why you can not add `repository` in your project

Comment: because repository have inbuilt `findall()` method for retrive data from database without query

Comment: I am not very clear about this annotation, I just follow the steps of others when I try

Comment: I don't have a deep understanding of springboot. There are many articles on the Internet, such as Spring, Springboot, JPA, Mybatis, Mybatis plus, and the result of the same code error confuses me.