# Cannot load driver class: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, mysql-8.0

I am unable to connect to mysql database with the below code

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource.url = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
spring.datasource.driverClassName = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:241) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:193) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Someone please let me know what's the mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you provided incorrect `datasource url` and `datasource driver class name`. Try the below one, hopefully it will work

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MyDatabase
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Comment: It worked but now I am getting below error.

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: username and password are correct. I cross checked it.

Comment: I have followed the steps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: I am using Mac OSX

Comment: Try to create new mysql user and then use this new user. You can checkout this https://howchoo.com/webdev/how-to-add-a-mysql-user-and-grant-privileges or just search google to create new mysql user in macos.

Comment: I have created a new user "aman" by following the steps on the above link. Still getting same error. Access denied for user 'aman'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I also ran this command :  ALTER USER 'aman'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';