# (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) using Windows

Tags: php, mysql

i cannot log in to the MySQL server. This is the error message that i get "Cannot log in to the MySQL server"
"mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

this is my database.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

i've tried to log in with null password (no characters at all) but i got "#1932 - Table 'my_table_name' doesn't exist in engine" in all my database.

can someone please help me?. Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Error: : 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't specify DB name in single quotes, then You have to specify your database username in ENV with single quotes like

DB_USERNAME='root@localhost'

It maybe work