# Can't reinstall mariadb by 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' error

Tags: mysql, linux, archlinux

I'm a archlinux user. Traying to solve another problem I follow the instructions of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost). Now when I try to install mariadb again the following message appears

mysql.user table already exists!

even when I eliminate everything related to mariadb. So I skip that and continue to the others steps of the installation, but I can't go too far because I can't create a new user. The following message appears

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

and

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Any idea about how to solve this?

I tried write in the my.cnf file the `skip-grant-tables` option, but it didn't work.

Comment: Reinstalling server software does not mean that all databases are gone forever.  Have you deleted all data from disk? On my Debian system all databases are in `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: I deleted and uninstalled everything I found related to sql, but nothing change.