# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I searched a lot concerning this problem but I didnt find any good solution for me

My database name: employee_management_system

My Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My connexion to DB:

```
Host:127.0.0.1
Port:3306
user:root
password:root
SSL: enabled with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Run details:

```
2020-09-21 21:50:14.752  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : Starting SpringbootBackendApplication on DESKTOP-14EIKT2 with PID 4468 (C:\Users\L480\Desktop\Springboot-Backend\target\classes started by L480 in C:\Users\L480\Desktop\Springboot-Backend)
2020-09-21 21:50:14.755  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] n.j.s.SpringbootBackendApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-21 21:50:14.816  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-09-21 21:50:14.816  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-09-21 21:50:15.623  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-21 21:50:15.682  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-21 21:50:16.332  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-21 21:50:16.345  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-21 21:50:16.345  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-09-21 21:50:16.476  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-21 21:50:16.477  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1660 ms
2020-09-21 21:50:16.663  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-21 21:50:16.720  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-21 21:50:16.765  WARN 4468 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-09-21 21:50:16.778  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-21 21:50:16.956  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-21 21:50:17.082  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-21 21:50:17.180  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-09-21 21:50:17.227  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-21 21:50:17.229  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-21 21:50:18.540 ERROR 4468 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2020-09-21 21:50:18.542  WARN 4468 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-09-21 21:50:18.573  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
2020-09-21 21:50:19.163  INFO 4468 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-21 21:50:20.200 ERROR 4468 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2020-09-21 21:50:20.203  WARN 4468 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
2020-09-21 21:50:20.203 ERROR 4468 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2020-09-21 21:50:20.218  WARN 4468 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao' defined in net.javaguides.springboot.dao.EmployeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2020-09-21 21:50:20.221  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-21 21:50:20.222  WARN 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2020-09-21 21:50:20.222  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-21 21:50:20.253  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-09-21 21:50:20.268  INFO 4468 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-09-21 21:50:20.272 ERROR 4468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao' defined in net.javaguides.springboot.dao.EmployeeDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution....................



Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have one entity **employee** in model and one interface **employeeDao** in repository which inherits one method from jpaRepository findALL used in one class **EmployeeController** controller folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is not related to Spring Framework or Spring Boot.
The root cause is your MySQL configuration.

TLRD: you need to grant access to the `root` user from `localhost`. The same issue was asked and answered many times on StackOverflow already [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror), ...

You can try to configure you application like the following in order to fix your problem:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employee_management_system
```

Comment: @koribaro if this works, consider to accept an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

For any others that face similar issue: If your datasource URL is incorrect with any typos or incorrect URL format, due to which it will not be able to make a connection, you may get this error as well.

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

In my case, I had datasource URL value as `jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/upic`, it was missing a `/` which made it incorrect. Changing it to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/upic` fixed the issue for me.

However, stacktrace for this issue is slightly different in root cause.